# DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter does not deserialize using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, serialization, json-deserialization

I am using WCF RESTful webservice and I am getting this error:

> There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   [http://tempuri.org/:aa](http://tempuri.org/%3aaa). The InnerException message was 'There was an
>   error deserializing the object of type WcfService1.Test. DateTime
>   content '2014-05-31T18:30:00.000Z' does not start with '/Date(' and
>   end with ')/' as required for JSON.'. Please see InnerException for
>   more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack
>   trace is:`
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo part) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo part) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, PartInfo returnInfo,
>   Object& returnValue) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyCore(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at

Input from jQuery:

```
          $.ajax({
                    url: "Restful.svc/new/one",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify({ aa: { xaaaaaa: "2014-05-31T18:30:00.000Z" } }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: true,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.helloWorldResult);
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        var y = 0;
                    }
                });
```

WCF Service:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "new/one")]
        String helloWorld(Test aa);
```

Test class:

```
    public class Test
    {
         [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
         public DateTime xaaaaaa { get; set; }
    }
```

If I pass the input `xaaaaaa` as : `/Date(new Date.valueOf().toString())/` it takes in. How do I change the default date formatter in the WCF Service to use IsoDateFormat for serialize and deserializing.

I have tried modifying the route table settings but I was not able to find most of the libraries. If I use JSON.NET it says it uses ISO format by default. How do I set it to take it in the WCF web service?

Comment: Similar post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105856/send-json-date-to-wcf-service

Comment: I did the exact same thing and I had to do trim off the quotes (") once the serializing was done. This was because the DataContract serializer (which is a default serializer in WCF service) serializes the final result and adds quotes around it ( Example: `"\"0001-01-01T00:00:00"\"`, when received on client side ).
Thank you @Irb it works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using Newtonsoft to serialize the date format to hold ISODate format. I was able to solve my problem doing this:

Test.cs:

```
[DataContract]
public class Test
{
    public DateTime xaaaaaa { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "xaaaaaa")]
    private string HiredForSerialization { get; set; }

    [OnSerializing]
    void OnSerializing(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        this.HiredForSerialization = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.xaaaaaa).Replace('"',' ').Trim();
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        this.xaaaaaa = DateTime.Parse(this.HiredForSerialization);
    }

}
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Transfer.svc/new/one",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ aa: { xaaaaaa: "2014-05-31T18:30:00.000Z" } }),
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: true,
    success: function (msg) {
    tester = msg.helloWorldResult; //"2014-06-01T00:00:00+05:30"
    },
    error: function (msg) {
    var y = 0;
    }
});
```

Date I selected from the date picker (jQuery):

[image: Selected date : 1st-Jun-2014]

WCF Service Looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "new/one")]
    public Test helloWorld(Test aa)
    {
        return aa;
    }
```

This works great!

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed.