# Datetime property is not binding causing the model to be null.

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

My WebAPI is expecting a model like below:

Model:

```
public class MyModel 
{
  public DateTime datetime {get;set; }
}
```

WebAction Method:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] MyModel model)
```

I am using `RestSharp` to send a request.

```
            var restRequest = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST)
            {
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
            };

            restRequest.AddBody(new MyModel {Datetime =DateTime.Now}, "");
```

But the model binding is always null (in the webapi side).

I see the following in Fiddler:
`{"datetime":"2014-09-25T07:22:56.7095909Z}"`

Any ideas why ?

Comment: is property name "datetime" in the model and "Date" in the request a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally seems the `new JsonMediaTypeFormatter {UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true};` turned out to be the culprit.

**In Detail:**

At `WebApiConfig` class, I have tried to make the `XmlSerializer` the default one instead of `JsonSerializer` which is the default one in `WebApi`.

But unknowingly I have set `UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true`.  This turned out to be the culprit.

Actually, `UseDataContractJsonSerializer` is primarily used to support `WCF` serialization. It serializes all the model properties which is has been marked as `DataContract`.

The problem with this is , this serializer expects the `date` to be in `epoch` format.

In the wire, the date time property behaves as given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx).

I referred this in SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474352/send-jquery-json-to-wcf-rest-using-date) and this SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105856/send-json-date-to-wcf-service) explains this even more beautifully.

Since I was using a serializer that is designed for `WCF`, it expects the date in the ASP.NET format (e.g.), `\/Date(1234567890)\/.`

And note that the default serializer in `WebAPI` is  NewtonSoft Json Serializer. Read more in [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/04/json-dates-are-different-in-aspnet-mvc.html#.Ufvl1Y3VD6Q)

So, to use a Json serializer in `WebApi` just do `new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()` alone.

Answer (score 2):

Change the request to:

`restRequest.AddBody(new MyModel { datetime =DateTime.Now}, "");`

In Fiddler, you want to be seeing this:

`{"datetime":"2014-09-25T07:22:56.7095909Z}"`

Since that will match the name of the property in your class:

`public DateTime datetime {get;set; }`

Model binding should then be able to pick that up from the request and, using reflection, find a property named "datetime" in a MyType instance and set a value to it.

Comment: I'm guessing he just posted a typo, otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Can update the question with values you now see in Fiddler please? It surely can't be `{"Date":"2014-09-25T07:22:56.7095909Z}"`? As a side note, although it's just a typo, it had massive implications as to whether this question could be answered successfully.

Comment: @JasonEvans: Thank you. I have updated the question. Also, is it because my `webapi` uses a different `dateformat` ?

Comment: Could you remove the `[FromBody]` attribute and let us know what happens. What is the result? Any difference?

Comment: @JasonEvans: Unfortunately, still the model binding is null. I will now upload a very basic sample here in a few secs

Comment: What happens if you change the API method to be `public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] DateTime datetime)`? I've been reading this http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/   which has some tips.

Comment: @JasonEvans: Thanks for your help. Finally figured out and have given a detailed explanation below :)